# 2004 ford focus Dual Radio loses memory like the time every time the car is shut off?

Tags: electrical, ford, audio, focus

I just replaced the radio in my 2004 Ford Focus to a Dual Radio and now every time the car shuts off. The time and memory erase and I have to program it again when the car is running. Please help?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

When you installed the radio, there should have been two power wires. One which is switched (main power) and the other which is constant and keeps the memory in the radio when you shut the car off. I suspect you didn't set these up correctly or didn't attach the memory power wire to a constant power source.

Comment: OK thank you. I will have to go back out and recheck. Thank you

Comment: I went out and checked the wires switched them around and made sure that all wires were connected. Is it possible to run a wire from the battery directly?

Comment: I replaced the radio bc of volume button didn't work, cd player didn't work and random hisses noises?

Comment: this radio I was just talking about was the original car radio.

Comment: @virg78 - Check to ensure the fuse is good which powers the memory.